# Why does the print command in gdb return \035 for C++ std::strings?

Tags: c++, string, printing, gdb

Say I have the code:

```
std::string str = "random";

function(str);

void function (std::string str)
{
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

If I step through this code in gdb and then go into the function and do `p str` it would print out something like this `\362\241` but the cout will print to the screen the correct string `random`.  Has anyone seen this before if so what should I do?  Am I using the print command wrong in gdb or does it have something to do with how the compiler interprets the string?

Comment: isn't \035 interpreted as an octal triplet indexed into the ASCII table?

Comment: I was thinking along these lines too, but I couldn't quite make out why, how or if this had anything to do with the problem

Comment: How to superset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606048/pretty-printing-stl-containers-in-gdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a broken version of GCC, or GDB, or you are trying to print the string at the wrong place. Here is what it should look like (using `g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3` and `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2.50.20110127-cvs` with STL pretty printers enabled):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void function (std::string str)
{
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::string str = "random";
  function(str);
}

$ g++ -g t.cc && gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from /usr/local/tmp/a.out...done.
(gdb) b function
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400b30: file t.cc, line 6.
(gdb) run

Breakpoint 1, function (str="random") at t.cc:6
6     std::cout << str << std::endl;
(gdb) p str
$1 = "random"
(gdb) q
```

P.S. You should probably pass the string into function as a const reference.

Comment: "You have a broken version of GCC, or GDB" - Haha. Apple's latest Xcode (4.5.2 in 2012).

Answer (score 10):

GDB is probably missing debug information for the STL for whatever reason.  Using [Employed Russian's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830279/print-command-in-gdb-return-035-on-strings/4830536#4830536) with g++ (GCC) 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1 and GNU gdb 6.8.0.20080328-cvs (cygwin-special), I get the following output:

```
(gdb) p str
$1 = {static npos = <optimized out>,
  _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<
No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x28cce8 "$▒▒"}}
```

Which is an interpretation of the raw data fields in `std::string`.  To get the actual string data, I have to reinterpret the `_M_p` field as a pointer:

```
(gdb) p *(char**)str._M_dataplus._M_p
$2 = 0xd4a224 "random"
```

Answer (score 6):

gdb is probably just showing you the byte-string-interpretation of the string class' internals. Try this to verify/work around:

```
$ print str.c_str()
```

Comment: What would be the best want to actually look at the string then, do you have a gdb command that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile your binary with debug information? Like `g++ -g test.cpp`

Mine is showing correct information:

```
(gdb) p s
$2 = {static npos = <optimized out>, 
  _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x804b014 "Hello world"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, solved including `iostream` library.