# How to pretty-print STL containers in GDB?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, stl, gdb

I've followed the instructions [on the GDB wiki](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) to install the python pretty-printers for viewing STL containers. My `~/.gdbinit` now looks like this:

```
python 
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/gdb_prettyprint/python') 
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers 
register_libstdcxx_printers (None) 
end
```

However, when I run GDB and attempt to print an STL type, I get the following:

```
print myString
Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> No type named std::basic_string<char>::_Rep.: 
$3 =
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, which comes with GDB 7.4.

Comment: It could simply be that the C++ library have changed its internal types and member variables, and the Python module haven't been keeping up.

Comment: Could you please paste more information, such as the C++ source, compiler options etc? I just tested this on Ubuntu 12.04 and it works for me.

Comment: Worked for me on CEntOS 7. One potential error to look is right when you start gdb. It might print a python error that you could have missed.

Comment: (*advertisement*) There are some things I don't like about the default pretty-printers `libstdcxx`, so [I made some modifications](https://github.com/user202729/gdb-custom-printers).

Answer (score 15):

**It just works on Ubuntu 17.04**

Debian seems to have finally integrated things properly now:

main.cpp

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(0);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    std::map<int,int> m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(0, 0));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(1, -1));
    m.insert(std::make_pair(2, -2));
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ -O0 -ggdb3 -o main.out -std=c++98 main.cpp
```

Outcome:

```
(gdb) p v
$1 = std::vector of length 3, capacity 4 = {0, 1, 2}
(gdb) p m
$2 = std::map with 3 elements = {[0] = 0, [1] = -1, [2] = -2}
```

We can see that the pretty printer is installed with:

```
(gdb) info pretty-printer
```

Which contains the lines:

```
global pretty-printers:
  objfile /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 pretty-printers:
  libstdc++-v6
    std::map
    std::vector
```

The printers are provided by the file:

```
/usr/share/gcc-7/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py
```

which comes with the main C++ library package `libstdc++6` and is located under `libstdc++-v3/python/libstdcxx` in the GCC source code:
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-6.3.0/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py#L244

TODO: how GDB finds that file is the final mistery, it is not in my Python path: `python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"` so it must be hardcoded somewhere?

**Custom classes**

See how to define a custom `toString` method and call it at: [Printing C++ class objects with GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163261/printing-c-class-objects-with-gdb/58310207#58310207)

**Inspect specific elements in optimized code**

It was hard last time I checked, you get "Cannot evaluate function -- may be in-lined" [C++, STL, GDB: Cannot evaluate function maybe inlined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633787/c-stl-gdb-cannot-evaluate-function-maybe-inlined)

On unoptimized code it works: [Inspecting standard container (std::map) contents with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427589/inspecting-standard-container-stdmap-contents-with-gdb)

Comment: @Evg I haven't looked further into it. It works for me, just I don't know how exactly. Let me know if you find out the detail.

Comment: Regarding the TODO (from https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/libstdc++/2009-02/msg00056.html): 
Printers can be auto-loaded by gdb when it reads an objfile. gdb looks for a file that is the objfile's real name with "-gdb.py" added; e.g., libstdc++.so.6.0.11-gdb.py.

Answer (score 12):

You can try with below **GDB macro** (append it to your **~/.gdbinit** file) to print STL containter types data and even their data members: https://gist.github.com/3978082

Answer (score 7):

I ran on this problem and hit this page while trying to figure it out. I eventually fixed it, and I thought it would be worth it to share my experience.

I am using gcc-5.2, so I downloaded the gcc-5-branch version of pretty printer from the svn repo. However, I had to do these two mods:

1. when editing the `~/.gdbinit` file, the suggested addition is

   ```
   python
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(0, '/home/bartgol/.gdb/gdb_printers/python')
   from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
   register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
   end
   ```

However, I had to comment the line `register_libstdcxx_printers (None)`, since I kept getting an error telling me the libstdcxx_printers were already registered. Apparently they get registered during the import phase.

2. I had to edit the printers.py file for `std::set` and `std::map`. Since the type `_Rep_type` is private in both. In particular, I replace the routine `children` in `std::map` and `std::set` with the corresponding one in the version of pretty printer from the gcc-4_6-branch version on the svn repo. Got no error ever since, and stuff prints out nicely now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me with custom-compiled GDB on Ubuntu 18.04 and gcc-9 from `ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` repo. I just had to alter the path to `/usr/share/gcc-9/python/`.

Answer (score 5):

Check your gcc version. If it is less than 4.7, you need use another printer.py file. Get the file from http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/gcc-4_6-branch/libstdc++-v3/python/.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of methods listed in [the link you mentioned](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport), you can try the script [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/src/dbinit_stl_views-1.03.txt),

Do as follows:

1) Download the script to `/your/path`. Name it to some name e.g. `your_name.conf`.

2) Add a `~/.gdbinit` file to home directory if you don't have one.

3) Add a line `source /your/path/your_name.conf` to your `~/.gdbinit`.

4) Restart gdb.  Try `pvector`

You can find help information with commands like `help pvector`.

e.g.

```
pvector vec 5      # Prints element[5] in vec
pvector vec 5 10   # Prints elements in range [5, 10] in vec. (5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

FYI, [the script](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/src/dbinit_stl_views-1.03.txt) adds several commands (`pvector`, `plist`, `pmap` etc.) to gdb whose function is to print the elements of STL. It also adds `print pretty`, yielding nice format like this:

[image]

Also, if you wanna know how exactly the elements of STL are accessed in gdb, just read the code of the commands. There's no secret in the code. ^_^

e.g. 
vectors are accessed by `._M_impl._M_start`

`p vec._M_impl._M_start + 4    # prints vec[4]`

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [enter link description here](https://www.gonwan.com/2014/07/02/setting-up-pretty-printers-in-gdb/)
Worked for me in ~/.gdbinit:

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/share/gcc-8/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you type `info type _Rep` after the Python exception, gdb will inform you about the classes loaded that match _Rep. That list could help you to find why python cannot find your `std::string class`.

I just faced your problem and in my case was intel c compiler, icc, who broke pretty printing. In particular, unqualified icc name for `std::string` results in:

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep;
```

but pretty printer was looking for unqualified gcc name:

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>::_Rep;
```

What I did to solve my problem was modifying class `StdStringPrinter` in printers.py, adding the unqualified name of the string to the typename to look in gdb. Replacing the line:

```
reptype = gdb.lookup_type (str (realtype) + '::_Rep').pointer ()
```

with this:

```
reptype = gdb.lookup_type (str (realtype) + '::' + str (realtype) + '::_Rep').pointer ()
```

With the obtained list from `info type` you could fix your pretty printers to make them work.

Answer (score 2):

Errors like you post above usually appears when program is LLVM-build (compiled by `clang`), and you try to debug it by `gdb` (which should be used for GCC-build programs).
In theory, LLVM-build program may be debugged by `gdb`, and vice versa. But
to avoid problems like posted above, you should use `lldb` if you use `clang`, and should use `gdb` if you use `g++`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a non-GNU STL library, or possible a very old GCC `libstdc++`. The type of a normal STL string on my compiler is: `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >`. Note that this is not `std::basic_string<char>`.

The Python code has this in it:

```
reptype = gdb.lookup_type (str (realtype) + '::_Rep').pointer ()
```

This look up a nested type `::Rep` of whatever the base string type actually is. The error message inidicates that the string class of whatever strange library you're using doesn't actually have a `::Rep` nested type.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on my system as well.

For me the fix was the following

In ~/.gdbinit

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '<path/to/gcc/dir>/GCCcore/9.3.0/share/gcc-9.3.0/python/')
exec(open("<path/to/gcc/dir>/GCCcore/9.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py").read())
end
```

The issues is that the `python` folder that contains the pretty printers was not part of python's search `path` (just like you would normally need to add your python modules location to `$PYTHONPATH`).  The first command accomplishes that.  The next issue is that now the pretty printers need to be loaded.  GCC provides a script for doing so in `GCCcore/9.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py` on my system. The second command 'sources' this script which will load the printers.

---

##### PS

Before making this modification I also got the following error:

```
warning: File "<path/to/gcc/dir>/GCCcore/9.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
```

Which can be fixed by adding the following to the gdb init file

```
add-auto-load-safe-path  <path/to/gcc/dir>/software/GCCcore/9.3.0/
```

However, this still does not allow the pretty printers to work (because of the path still not being set), and after the python fix above, is not needed.