# How to enable pretty-printing in arm-none-eabi-gdb?

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, gdb, stm32

I use C++ to develop for STM32, when debugging, it's hard to monitor the values in stl containers.

Environment:

- VSCode, with cortex-debug, Embedded IDE plug-ins
- arm-none-eabi-gdb 12.2
- SEGGER JLink

The Embedded IDE automaticly generated a `launch.json` file:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "type": "cortex-debug",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "JLink",
        "servertype": "jlink",
        "interface": "swd",
        "executable": "build\\debug\\RP_CppTemplate.elf",
        "runToEntryPoint": "main",
        "device": "STM32F407VE",
        "svdFile": ".pack/Keil/STM32F4xx_DFP.2.14.0/CMSIS/SVD/STM32F40x.svd",
        "liveWatch": {
            "enabled": true,
            "samplesPerSecond": 4
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pretty-print STL containers in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606048/how-to-pretty-print-stl-containers-in-gdb)